# How to change angle of gradient Weight Paint?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

I am beginner and this is the simple 2D project.

Is it possible to mess with angle of gradient Weight Paint?

I know how to make this:

[image]

But I would need something like this (sorry for hand-paint, fastest way :) ):

[image]

Please let me know if you need any additional data, thanks in advance.